# Does $\mathbb E\epsilon^2 = const$ and $\mathbb V\epsilon = const$ are equivalent conditions for homoskedasticity?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity

Wooldridge states in his book that homoskedasticity requires $$\mathbb V[\epsilon\mid x] = const.$$ But I often encounter that $\mathbb E[\epsilon^2\mid x] = const$ is required for homoskedasticity and I wonder if both conditions are equivalent. Clearly, if $\mathbb E[\epsilon\mid x] = 0$ this is the case, but this assumption may be violated while the errors could still be homoskedastic, right? Or does a violation of $\mathbb E[\epsilon^2\mid x] \neq const$ also implies $\mathbb V[\epsilon\mid x]\neq const$ and vice versa (irrespective of $\mathbb E[\epsilon\mid x] = 0$).